# I need to modify code that simulates the "Draw a stick" game and add a cycle where the game doesn´t end until the shortest stick is picked

Tags: python

I need to modify this code to make the game cycle back to the question of choosing an option until the shortest stick is picked. I also need to erase the stick that was drawn from the options so there´re only four sticks left by the second cycle, three on the third, and so on.

```
    """
        Program that simulates the game of the shortest stick. Getting the shortest stick
        means losing.
    """
    import random

    def shuffle_sticks(stick_list):
        """
        Function to shuffle a list
        :param: stick_list:
        :return: list
        """
        random.shuffle(stick_list)
        return stick_list

    def validate_selection():
        """
        Validate correct selection from the user
        :return: int
        """
        option = ""
        while option not in ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]:
            option = input("Please enter a number between 1 and 5: ")
        return int(option)

    def choose_stick(stick_list, choosing):
        """
        Function to choose the stick and see if you lose
        :param stick_list:
        :param choosing:
        :return:
        """
        if stick_list[choosing-1] == "-":
            print("Unlucky! Time to wash the dishes!")
        else:
            print("Whew, you´re safe!")

        print(f"You got {stick_list[choosing-1]}")

    sticks = ["-", "--", "---", "----", "-----"]
    mixed_sticks = shuffle_sticks(sticks)
    correct_selection = validate_selection()
    choose_stick(mixed_sticks, correct_selection)
```

```
def choose_stick(stick_list, choosing):
"""
Function to choose the stick and see if you lose
:param stick_list:
:param choosing:
:return:
"""
while stick_list[choosing-1] != "-":
    if stick_list[choosing-1] == "-":
        print("Unlucky! Time to wash the dishes!")
        exit()
    else:
        print("Whew, you´re safe!")
        stick_list[choosing-1].pop()
    print(f"You got {stick_list[choosing-1]}")
```

I tried using a while cycle (until the shortest stick was drawn) but it looped endlessly. I tried using `.pop()` when deleting the drawn stick from the options, but it didn't work. Been trying to find a few other solutions but I haven't been able to make them work. The second choose_stick function is what I tried to do, but I just tried something to see if it would work.

Comment: Show us the code you actually tried.  Otherwise we can only guess what you did wrong.

Comment: def choose_stick(stick_list, choosing):
    """
    Function to choose the stick and see if you lose
    :param stick_list:
    :param choosing:
    :return:
    """
    while stick_list[choosing-1] != "-":
        if stick_list[choosing-1] == "-":
            print("Unlucky! Time to wash the dishes!")
            exit()
        else:
            print("Whew, you´re safe!")
            stick_list[choosing-1].pop()
        print(f"You got {stick_list[choosing-1]}")
That is the last thing I tried, it´s not very different from the original function, my other attempts are lost.

Comment: It's very hard to read code in comments.  Please edit the question and add it there.

Comment: I´ll edit it, sorry about the inconveniences, it´s my first post here.

Comment: Sorry for the wait, I added the last thing I tried to do with the choose_stick function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a few problems.

1. The syntax of `pop` is wrong.
2. Even if the `pop` function worked correctly, you are only changing the list inside the function (wrong scope).
3. The user should be prompted to input a new option at each turn, and the number of options needs to change at each turn.

To fix these problems, I changed the code to call `choose_stick` with the new list recursively at each turn. `validate_selection` also gets called at each turn with a reduced number of options.

```
"""
    Program that simulates the game of the shortest stick. Getting the shortest stick
    means losing.
"""
import random

def shuffle_sticks(stick_list):
    """
    Function to shuffle a list
    :param: stick_list:
    :return: list
    """
    random.shuffle(stick_list)
    return stick_list

def validate_selection(option_list=["1","2","3","4","5"]):
    """
    Validate correct selection from the user
    :return: int
    """
    option = ""
    while option not in option_list:
        option = input(f"Please enter a number between 1 and {len(option_list)}: ")
    return int(option)

def choose_stick(stick_list, choosing):
    """
    Function to choose the stick and see if you lose
    :param stick_list:
    :param choosing:
    :return:
    """
    if stick_list[choosing-1] == "-":
        print("Unlucky! Time to wash the dishes!")
    else:
        print("Whew, you´re safe!")
        print(f"You got {stick_list[choosing-1]}")
        stick_list.pop(choosing-1)
        choose_stick(stick_list,validate_selection([str(i) for i in range(1,len(stick_list)+1)]))
    


sticks = ["-", "--", "---", "----", "-----"]
mixed_sticks = shuffle_sticks(sticks)
correct_selection = validate_selection()
choose_stick(mixed_sticks, correct_selection)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to re-ask user for input every iteration of while loop (don't forget to change list of options - you can use [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp))
2. Syntax of pop is wrong, it should be `stick_list.pop(choosing-1)`